# How to verify the Digital Signature at the Apache Level?

Tags: digital-signature, docusignapi, x509, apache2.2

I have a Docusign Connect Configuration to an API endpoint with the option **Sign Message with X509 Certificate** selected.

What configurations are required at the Apache (Directory) level to verify the Digital signature that is sent along with the Docusign Payload.

I have tried putting

> SSLVerifyClient require

at the directory level. It is still allowing the request when I uncheck the **Sign Message with X509 Certificate** option.

I want only those Request to be allowed which has a valid signature. I have the public key provided by the Docusign for the DEMO instances.

Please help me in putting the correct configuration for rejecting the unsigned request or a request with the altered signature.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to Allow only requests that come from DocuSign with Apache, you should use Mutual TLS instead of trying to verify the signature.

Properly verifying the signature can only be done with some code behind Apache.

Mutual TLS will require a certificate authentication to be able to pass SSL Handcheck, this is what you tried to achieve with SSLVerifyClient

So, this is what you should do

1. Enable Mutual TLS in Connect configuration
2. Configure your apache with something like

   ```
   SSLCACertificateFile    /path/to/ca-bundle  
   SSLVerifyClient require
   SSLVerifyDepth  3
   SSLRequire %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN}  eq "demo.connect.docusign.net"
   ```

DocuSign Connect certificate : https://trust.docusign.com/en-us/trust-certifications/docusign-public-certificates/

Check: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_ssl.html to be more precise with SSLRequire or for explication about SSLCACertificateFile